# Ajax complete function not setting background-image even when json response is successful

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, wordpress

I am developing a theme in wordpress and i am not being able to set a background-image in spite of getting a successful ajax response.

I am requesting an image url that is being successfully given in the json response except that i am not being able to set the image as a background image.

I am using the following ajax function:

```
function Pat_Req(pat_val){
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: BAC_PAT_OBN.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action' : 'BAC_PAT_Ajax',
                'nonce' : BAC_PAT_OBN.nonce,
                'rpat' : parseInt(pat_val)
            },
            complete: function( object ) {
                $('#pat_bac').css('background-image',object.responseJSON.response_pat)
            }
        });
    }
```

"pat_val" is an integer that i am getting from an input of type number.
I tested to see if "pat_val" is actually storing an integer from the input and it does store an integer.

When the input values changes to say, 5, "pat_val" stores 5.

The Pat_Req function is triggered every time there is a change in the input value. the following jquery code is doing it:

```
$('#The_pats input').on('change',function(){
    Pat_Req($(this).val())
})
```

"BAC_PAT_OBN" is the javascript object i am using.

"object.responseJSON.res_pat" is also giving me a valid image url. The only problem is that Pat_Req complete function is not setting the background.

Thank you for your time and answer,
MMK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you showed the Ajax response, it would be easier to answer. My guess is you are not returning url() surrounding the image path.

```
$('#pat_bac').css('background-image', "url(" + object.responseJSON.response_pat + ")");
```

Comment: Than you should review the MDN Docs [background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)